# WCF service broadcasts Resolve, Hello, Probe discovery messages

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm implementing WCF discovery for my application. Everything works fine, except spurious traffic in our network.
With the help of Wireshark I've discovered that service sends "Hello", "Probe" and "Resolve" messages to 239.255.255.250:3702 address. According to WCF Discovery specification client should send "Hello", "Probe" message to find the service and service should send announcement "Hello" message when using managed discovery.
As I understand there is no reason for the service to broadcast messages when there is no search. Client should just send "Hello/Probe" message and service should answer with "ResolveMatches/ProbeMatches" message one time.
Is there any way to turn off such behaviour of the service?

My config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Base">
      <endpointDiscovery>
        <extensions>
          <interfaces>192.168.36.16</interfaces>
        </extensions>
      </endpointDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RadioServer">
      <serviceDiscovery />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Base" receiveTimeout="Infinite">
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:00:15" enabled="true" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="Sign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RadioServer" name="Server.RadioServer">
    <endpoint address="RS" behaviorConfiguration="Base" binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="Base" contract="Common.IRadioService" />
    <endpoint name="udpDiscovery" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8888/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Examples of "Hello", "Probe", "Resolve" messages from the service:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery">
 <soap:Header>
 <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To>
 <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Resolve</wsa:Action>
 <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:95bc52ec-e466-41b4-971a-3ae6dfe6f864</wsa:MessageID>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
 <wsd:Resolve>
 <wsa:EndpointReference>
 <wsa:Address>urn:uuid:9525082d-d921-40f6-b81e-5c953bec55c1</wsa:Address>
 </wsa:EndpointReference>
 </wsd:Resolve>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:wsdp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/devprof" xmlns:pub="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pub/2005/07">
 <soap:Header>
 <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To>
 <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Hello</wsa:Action>
 <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d950c11f-46a5-408b-8e54-d530f225af89</wsa:MessageID>
 <wsd:AppSequence InstanceId="6" SequenceId="urn:uuid:330912d7-9365-4029-8fbc-f93749e46089" MessageNumber="487489"></wsd:AppSequence>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
 <wsd:Hello>
 <wsa:EndpointReference>
 <wsa:Address>urn:uuid:9525082d-d921-40f6-b81e-5c953bec55c1</wsa:Address>
 </wsa:EndpointReference>
 <wsd:Types>wsdp:Device pub:Computer</wsd:Types>
 <wsd:MetadataVersion>950</wsd:MetadataVersion>
 </wsd:Hello>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:wsdp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/devprof">
 <soap:Header>
 <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To>
 <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action>
 <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:3785aebe-d04b-48fc-8010-5403a56777fd</wsa:MessageID>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
 <wsd:Probe>
 <wsd:Types>wsdp:Device</wsd:Types>
 </wsd:Probe>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```